# Autostart GUI application with X using a specific user&group

Tags: bash

What would be the best method to use when you want to autostart a specific program with X under a particular user&group?

My program has GUI, so I can't use systemd

I would like it to autostart with X without asking for a sudo password.

```
sudo -H -u $USER bash -c "newgrp $GROUP && /bin/command"
```

This is close.. But it asks me for my sudo password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo` can set the primary group with the `-g` option, so there's no need to use `newgrp`.  You can also configure `sudo` to allow your user to run `/bin/command` as any user without a password.

e.g.  add the following to `/etc/sudoers` (do **NOT** edit this file directly.  Use `visudo`. It sanity-checks your changes so that you can't make syntax errors that would invalidate the entire sudoers file. You can still make logical mistakes, but it won't let you break /etc/sudoers to the point that you can't use `sudo` at all):

```
username ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/command
```

Then run it as:

```
sudo -H -u "$USER" -g "$GROUP" /bin/command
```

---

If you want to restrict which usernames and/or groups the command may be run as, change the `ALL` inside the parentheses.  e.g.

```
cas ALL = (fred, bob : mygroup, othergroup) NOPASSWD: /bin/command
```

would allow user `cas` to run `/bin/command` as either user `fred` or user `bob` with groups `mygroup` or `othergroup` without a password.  See `man sudoers` and search for the section headed `Runas_Spec`.

BTW, the first `ALL` (before the `=`) refers to the hostnames that this rule applies to. It's only important if you share the same sudoers file on multiple machines and you have sysadmins who need permission to use `sudo` to run certain commands on some machines but not others. Search for `Host_List` in `man sudoers` for details.

NOTE: `sudo` is very complex and very flexible.  It is worth putting in the effort to read the man pages for `sudo` and `sudoers` repeatedly until they make sense to you.  It is very easy to make mistakes that grant less or, worse, more privileges than you intended.

Comment: Thank you so much for your in-depth explanation!! :-)